# **screenWindow.setVisibleOnAllWorkspaces(true, {visibleOnFullScreen: true}); app is invisible in macOS dock

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I'm using  **screenWindow.setVisibleOnAllWorkspaces(true, {visibleOnFullScreen: true});**   for  window visible on full screen. it's working  fine. but app is invisible in macOS dock . If i remove **{visibleOnFullScreen: true}** then app is visible in macOS dock.  but  window invisible on full screen. please share me solution if anyone have idea about that. i'm using electron version **11.5.0**.